# How to run a script on boot?

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have the following commands I want to run when the raspberry pi boots up, it is for my bitcoin miner to start:

```
cd /home/pi/cgminer-4.5.0
sudo ./cgminer -o http://xxxxxxxxxxx -u xxxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxx
```

How can i do this ? as i have currently set it up using `nohup` but this only autostarts when I ssh into the pi and stops working when I close the connection, I want this code to run automatically on start up and keep running constantly

How can I do this ?

Comment: I guess you're doing it just for fun? With Pi's performance it probably won't even make up for the electricity it will consume.

Comment: Yeah its just for fun, not expecting it to make anything, just interested in how it works and stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few months since I was in my Raspbian install, but I believe you can add commands into your `/etc/rc.local` file (before the exit command) to have them load on boot. `sudo` will be unnecessary as it will be executed by root.